# Can't start a job with Cron on Ubuntu startup

Tags: python, startup, cron

I am trying to get a simple Python script running on startup with Cron on Ubuntu 16.04. What I did is opened cron with:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and added the last line as shown in the screenshot:
[image]

I even tried

```
@reboot without sudo later.
```

Then I do:

```
sudo reboot
```

But when Ubuntu starts the Python file seems to have not run. I also modified crontab by opening it as a simple user:

```
crontab -e
```

And added:

```
@reboot sudo python /my_script_path
```

Nothing worked.

The Python script is supposed to create a text file when executed. I have tested the Python script using the terminal and it successfully generates that text file.

Anyone know what I am missing here?

Edits: The Python script I am trying is a very simple one:

```
with open("example.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.write("Some text")
print("Done")
```

Comment: what is the source of the text .. in other words is it getting it from a service or program ... it may be a timing issue .. it may be trying to get the information before the place its trying to get the information is available. The script runs when cron starts which may be before the information is accessable

Comment: @JohnOrion it's a simple Python script (I edited my question adding the Python code). Would I need to add some delay in crontab somehow?

Comment: ok so you aren't grabbing text from anywhere .. everything is static... well that rules out that theory. sorry... no my theory was wrong .. if you arent actually getting the text from somewhere and its just static in your script then the issue i was talking about cant happen. It would have been something like if you were trying to read from a process to grab text from it but the script ran before the process was launched  so it didnt have any text to grab .. this doesn't fit for your situation  :(

Comment: @JohnOrion I am now suspecting cron is creating "example.txt" in the  cron directory because I am passing a relative path for the text file. I should maybe pass an absolute text file path.
I don't have my Ubuntu here at the moment to try that though.

Comment: you may be onto something there ... or maybe the root directory. Give me a few moments .. i will try it out with an absolute path and see if it works .. Ill slap it into a VM so I dont have to restart my server :D

Comment: you solved your own problem ... with the absolute path ..after reboot... example.txt was in the script folder

Comment: @JohnOrion you illuminated me and thanks for trying that out.